# Unable to return Postgres table names in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've created a database, a schema and some tables in pgadmin4. In python with SQL Alchemy, I am unable to return the tables names.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{pswd["Connection"]["user"]}:{pswd["Connection"]["pw"]}@{pswd["Connection"]["host"]}/{pswd["Connection"]["database"]}')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.execute('SET search_path TO schema_name;')
print(engine.table_names())
```

I found the "SET search_path TO schema_name" on another question, but its from 2013. I know the tables exist, I've been able to interact with psycopg2 alone. Any glaring reason as to why this may be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the docs, [`Engine.table_names()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.table_names) accepts the schema to look in as an argument:

```
print(engine.table_names("schema_name"))
```

Your `SET` is executed in a different connection from the one the `engine` uses.